# Graph Theory | How can I find the max. diameter of a given graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I would love any help given with a problem I'm facing with my homework:

Let $G(V,E)$ an arbitrary, undirected graph and denote $\mid V\mid$=n. If the rank of every node in $G$ is at least $\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\rceil$ then the diameter of $G$ is at least 2.

can someone direct me to any prove strategy for this claim? I tried to prove it by induction - suppose a graph with $V$ vertices upholds the claim, so if I'll add one more node to the graph and connect it to every other node, It would prove it, but I think now my prove isn't right because I assumed I can connect the added node to all of the other ones, which I can't.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you give the definition of the rank of a node?

Comment: the rank of a node= the number of edges between node v to another node.

Comment: This is false. The complete graph $K_n$ is a counterexample, its diameter is equal to $1.$

Comment: The complete graph $K_n$ is the **only** counterexample. Every graph $G$ which is not complete has diameter at least $2.$

Comment: Could "at least $2$" be a typo for "at most $2$?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that we have two points $A$ and $B$ which are not connected. And let $M$ and $N$ be the sets of the neighbors of $A$ respectively $B$. Then since $A$ and $B$ are not connected we have $A\notin N$ and $B\notin M$. Suppose they don't have common neighbor, so $M\cap N =\emptyset $. Now by PIE we have $$n-2\geq|M\cup N|=|M|+|N|-|M\cap N| \geq 2[{n-1\over 2}]$$
A contradiction. Thus $A$ and $B$ must have common neighbor and thus we have a path at least $2$.

If everybody are connected then this trivially holds.

Comment: But if you have a complete graph with $n>2$ nodes, then the number of neighbours of a node is exactly $n-1,$ which is obviously greater than $\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil$. But the diameter of the graph is 1, which is obviously less than 2.

Comment: The diameter is longest path, no?

Comment: It is the longest "shortest" path, which means that it is the greatest distance between any two nodes. In the complete graph, the distance between any two nodes is one, because everything is connected with everything.

Comment: Then I proved that such a graph is $K_n$.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! can you please just explain what 'by PIE' means? I either didn't learn it yet or didn't use this term before.

Comment: The principle of inclusion and exclusion

Comment: In the question, we are asked to prove that a certain condition holds for an *arbitrary*, undirected graph. If this graph turns out to be $K_n$, then this condition we are trying to prove is false. 
My guess is that there's a typo and we have to prove that the diameter is at *most* 2.

Comment: Or that $K_n$ is excepted.

Comment: If $K_n$ is excepted, then the diameter is *exactly* 2, not at least 2 (it can't possibly be more than 2).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you mean that the diameter of the graph has to be at *most* 2, since the claim is not true if you mean at *least* 2. I am also going to assume, without loss of generality, that the graph is connected (if it's not, then the proof will be done on its connected components and we will get the same results).

If the graph is $K_n$ then the diameter is equal to 1 and we are done.

If the graph is not $K_n$, this means that there exist 2 nodes, $x$ and $y$, which aren't connected. If $x$ and $y$ have a common neighbour, then the path formed by $x$, $y$ and this neighbour is of length 2, therefore the diameter is 2 (since $x$ and $y$ are arbitrarily chosen, with only restriction that they are not connected).

Now, suppose that $x$ and $y$ have no common neighbours. If we denote by $N(x)$ and $N(y)$ the neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively, then this means that $N(x) \cap N(y)=\emptyset$. So, we have $|N(x) \cup N(y)| = |N(x)| + |N(y)| - |N(x) \cap N(y)| \geq 2\frac{n-1}{2}=n-1$. Adding the nodes $x$ and $y$ to this sum, we get that the number of nodes of the graph is at least $n+1$, a contradiction.

Therefore the diameter can be at most 2.